# Printing a String with a Start and Length Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, tasm, x86-16

I was trying to build an Assembly Code, that ask for a string, start where the string would be printed and the desired length to be printed. *assume start and length are always valid* Can you help me to determine the start and length.

How it should work:

```
Enter String: Hello World
Enter Start: 3
Enter Length: 5
Mid-String: llo W
```

So I have a problem on how to determine the start and length of the string. I tried several things which is shown in my code below:

```
.model small
.stack
.data
msg1 db "Enter String:$"
msg2 db 13,10,"Enter Start:$"
msg3 db 13,10,"Enter Length:$"
msg4 db 13,10,"Mid-String:$"
nwln db 13,10
mySample label byte
maxlen db 10
actlen db 0
string db 19 dup (?)
.code
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
    lea dx, msg1 ;print msg1
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    lea dx,mySample ;accept string
    mov ah,0Ah
    int 21h

    mov bh,0
    mov bl,maxlen
    mov string[bx],'$'
    mov ah,9
    lea dx,string   ;print string accept
    int 21h

    lea dx, msg2    ;print msg2 and accept start
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    mov ah,1
    int 21h
    sub al,30h
    mov bh,0
    mov bl,al

    lea dx, msg3    ;print msg3 and accept length
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    mov ah,1
    int 21h
    sub al,30h
    mov dl,al

    ;mov maxlen,dl
    mov bh,0
    mov bl,maxlen
    mov string[bx],'$'
    lea dx,msg4     ;print msg4
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    lea dx,string   ;print mid-string
    int 21h
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
END
```

OUTPUT LOOKS LIKE:
[image: output from the code above]

Comment: When you single-step through this in a debugger, do the numbers you read in actually end up in registers like you expect?  Are the values in registers before the last `int 21h` what you expect them to be?  If not, work backwards to find where things first stopped behaving like you expected.

Comment: Chouny, there's a new answer to your question, check it out !

Answer (score 2):

Based on a quick look at the last few instructions, where you actually do the offset and print (assuming the rest of your code just prints and reads strings correctly):

You forgot to convert from ASCII to an integer, so you write the terminating `$` many bytes past the end of the string (`'0'` to be precise: the ASCII encoding of `0`).

You also don't appear to use the start offset for anything.  It would be easy to do something like `lea dx, [string + bx]` after getting `atoi(start_offset_string)` into BX.

Your length counts from the beginning of the original string, not from the offset position.  You might want to do the offset first.

Comment: i don't get it at all  I mean you need to accept a number to set the start of the string which I did and I put is as mov bl,al.

Comment: @Chouny: look at BL in a debugger in the part of the code right before it prints the string.  I see that instruction in your code, and I still think my answer is correct.  Writing asm without a debugger is like building a robot while blindfolded, so learn to use your debugger and you'll understand this answer.

Comment: BX = 000A, which is true, then BX= 0102 then 0002 then 000A again. I do not know what happened but I know that it does not get the start or so.

Answer (score 1):

I made some little changes to your code to make it work, those little changes are commented, basically, it was a matter of using pointers properly (pointers to start position and length), that I replaced by registers `SI` and `DI` :

```
.model small
.stack
.data
msg1 db "Enter String:$"
msg2 db 13,10,"Enter Start:$"
msg3 db 13,10,"Enter Length:$"
msg4 db 13,10,"Mid-String:$"
nwln db 13,10
mySample label byte
maxlen db 10
actlen db 0
string db 19 dup (?)
.code
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
    lea dx, msg1 ;print msg1
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    lea dx,mySample ;accept string
    mov ah,0Ah
    int 21h

    mov bh,0
    mov bl,actlen   ;◄■■■ NOT MAXLEN.
    mov string[bx],'$'
    mov ah,9
    lea dx,string   ;print string accept
    int 21h

    lea dx, msg2    ;print msg2 and accept start
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    mov ah,1
    int 21h
    sub al,30h
    mov bh,0
    mov bl,al
    mov si,bx       ;◄■■■ SAVE BX IN SI, BECAUSE WE WILL NEED
                    ;◄■■■  BX FOR SOMETHING ELSE (SI = "START").

    lea dx, msg3    ;print msg3 and accept length
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    mov ah,1
    int 21h
    sub al,30h
    mov bl,al       ;◄■■■ REPLACE DL BY BL BECAUSE DX WILL
                    ;◄■■■ BE USED TO DISPLAY WITH INT 21H.
    ;mov maxlen,dl
    mov bh,0        ;◄■■■ NOW BX = "LENGTH". BUT WE WILL NEED
    mov di,bx       ;◄■■■ BX AGAIN, SO LET'S MOVE "LENGTH" TO DI.

    ;mov bl,maxlen
    add di, si         ;◄■■■ CALCULATE END POSITION.
    dec di, 1          ;◄■■■ MINUS 1 BECAUSE IT STARTS IN 0.
    mov string[di],'$'
    lea dx,msg4     ;print msg4
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    ;lea dx,string   ;print mid-string
    mov dx,offset string
    add dx,si
    int 21h
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
END
```